# Which Perl modules does git for Windows come with?

Tags: git, perl, perl-module, cpan, msysgit

I want to write a Perl script that will work on Windows, which doesn't have Perl installed by default. The users are guaranteed to have git installed, so I am considering using that one.

But I don't know which modules are guaranteed to be present.  Is this documented somewhere?  If not, can I find out some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [App::FatPacker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App::FatPacker) to inline (non-XS) modules into your script.

Comment: I think this is actually the right answer, were it not for the fact I myself ALSO don't have a proper perl distribution.  But perhaps I should just download one.

Comment: It's pretty easy :)

Comment: A bit less easy without admin rights, but alright, alright, already.  I still feel that there should be a way to find this out though.

Comment: I doubt it. Why would they want to guarantee that a module will be present? The `perl` is there to serve `git`, nothing more.

Comment: You're probably right that this is likely undocumented and has no contractual guarantees, but this information should still exist somewhere.  Either by asking perl for what modules are present, or by finding it in the msys source code or install script, or something.  After all, the modules do get installed!  They have to come from somewhere :)

Comment: Again, why would someone take the time to do create the last of modules in each build?  Especially since it would encourage people to rely on it?

Comment: Because the installer needs it!  Somehow, the modules actually get installed, which means they come with the installer.  Somehow the installer gets built.  Thus, this information must exist somewhere.  Maybe not in a convenient form, but it has to exist.

Comment: @MarkVY: *"Because the installer needs it!"* You have an inflated idea about your own Perl code. The people creating the git installation package created something that would allow git to work. They weren't concerned with ***Mark VY's*** installation some time later, and nor should they have been. They may well have removed unnecessary core modules from that perl just to save wasted space. Your approach should be the same. Your software needs a copy of perl and some specific modules. You must release all of those with your Perl code so that it will run on an empty Windows system.

Comment: Huh?  I have no illusions of grandeur here.  I meant that _their_ installer needs it.  You've convinced me that I should not rely on it,  but it should exist.

Comment: You still assume that every build had the same packages even though I specifically pointed out that's not the case. OTOH, if you want to know what's on your hard drive, just look

Comment: @ΜarkVY: I hope you're convinced. Tomorrow they may well switch to a Python or Java layer that affects nothing but your hybrid installation. No release has any obligations beyond getting the target software working and leaving the rest of the system untouched. If you work with a Windows system of any age then you will find *dozens* of identical copies of standard .dll files. All of them are there to make sure that a single piece of software works as predicted by its suppliers. If you're happy to delete all copies of `system32.dll` except the one in the Windows tree then go ahead.

Comment: yes, I am indeed convinced that relying on specific modules being installed is asking for trouble.  in theory, relying on perl at all is asking for trouble, but in practice that seems far-fetched.  if that were to happen, I'd just ask people to install Perl.

Comment: @MarkVY: That's very unprofessional, but I'm beginning to think that you don't care. If you know about a potential problem but decide to wait until someone finds it before issuing the fix then you're being irresponsible. It's also highly likely that you may break something on the system if you just tell them to install some sort of Windows Perl. The git installation deliberately keeps its perl out of `PATH`, and you don't have a procedure for doing the same for your perl. Which modules are available is the least of your worries.

Answer (score 2):

My approach is a combination of some of the other suggestions along with a new wrinkle.

I'd start with using a portable edition of [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).  That's an easy way to get a good clean Perl installation without interfering with your git installation's Perl.  (Alternatively, you could look into using [berrybrew](https://github.com/stevieb9/berrybrew), which emulates [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) for the Windows environment by leveraging portable editions of Strawberry Perl.)

After you get your portable Strawberry Perl environment setup with the modules that you need for your script, use the cpan or cpanm client (included in Strawberry Perl) to install [PAR::Packer](https://metacpan.org/pod/PAR::Packer), which will provide you with the [pp](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp) utility.  Using the pp utility, you can bundle your Perl script into a standalone executable - which in turn can be run on another Windows system that does not have Perl installed.  When using the pp utility, be sure to use the -c and/or -x options to ensure that pp will pickup all of the run time dependencies to bundle those in as well.

Comment: That is very close to ikegami's idea.  This is probably the right answer; this way I'm the only one who has to install anything, and the recipient can use any Perl in the w, even one without any modules at all.

Comment: @MarkVY: Yes, this is a similar concept to ikegami's suggestion of App::FatPacker.  However, there are two key differences.  The App::FatPacker route would require Perl to be installed on the system that runs the script and you can't use any XS module (example: you'd have to use Text::CSV rather than Text::CSV_XS).  Using pp from PAR::Packer means the created executable can be run on a system that doesn't have Perl installed and you can use XS modules.  Basically pp packages the Perl interpreter, all of the needed modules and your script into a standalone executable.

Comment: Ah, I see.  But then I guess it will ONLY work on windows.

Comment: @MarkVY:  You can't use pp on one platform to build an executable for another platform.  For example, you can't use pp on a Windows system to build an executable to be run on a Linux system.  But based on your original question, it didn't sound like that was something that you were trying to do.

Comment: Most Linux systems have a proper installation of Perl with all or most core modules included; thus my main concern was with getting Windows to work.  Upon further investigation, it looks like the Perl that ships with git for windows also has most (though far from all) of the core modules included, so things are not as bad as I feared.

Answer (score 1):

For a Windows machine you need to install either
[Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/)
or possibly ActivePerl. You certainly shouldn't be relying on whatever happens to come with another distribution

Perl is developed very carefully so that it will mostly accept very old Perl code without change. But if your Perl has to perform identically on someone else's system then you may need to be more careful

What matters most is whether you need a 32-bit or a 64-bit version of Perl, and what version of the Perl compiler you need. You shouldn't concern yourself with what modules are available, as it is simple to add any Windows-compatible modules to the base installation

If you need more help than this then we need more information, which you should edit into your question

Comment: see C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\perl.exe

Comment: @MarkVY: That is a local path on specific machine. All it tells me is that there is a `perl.exe` under that system's git installation. What do you see if you enter `where perl` to a command prompt?

Comment: I think the bottom line is that your installation process must make sure that your code will run. Unless you can be certain of the heritage and integrity of any existing Perl installation, it is simplest to install your own Perl and requisite libraries and rely on those.

Answer (score -2):

brute force solution: install git on a windows machine that doesn't have it and see what modules show up.  ick!

Comment: What is wrong with just installing your dependencies along with the software? It's what the rest of the world does!

Comment: Is it really?  Does every project that requires Java ship its own JRE?

Comment: Often, yes. But Java is different and will offer to update itself if it phones home and finds that there is a later version available. That is Oracle's way of marketing. But Perl, Python, Ruby, Lua etc.all have different solutions to the problem, and all involve shipping the run time environment with the software in one way or another.

Comment: Lua is compact.  The other languages are not.  A typical Linux distribution has a reasonably nice solution to this kind of thing: package managers.  So if program 1 and program 2 both require Perl, you only end up with 1 copy of perl.  Windows doesn't have this.  But I personally resent it when I see programs 3 different programs installing their own version of Python 2.7 on my machine when I already had it installed for my own use, wasting who knows how much disk space.  They do this to simplify their installation instructions, because disk space is cheap and user training is hard. But still.

Comment: I'm not going to say any more here because you clearly have your own ideas of what a proper answer should say, and in any case it's the wrong place for an exchange of this length or nature. I would just remind you that you have access to the help of some of the very best software engineers in the world here, and it seems churlish of you to dismiss the answers that you are offered. No one with any sense will engage with you in trying to make use of an unknown version of Perl that should part of another installation on the target system, and will likely need additional modules.

Comment: I plead guilty to the accusation of churlishness.  I also mostly agree that hardly anyone with sense would assist me with what I'm trying to do, because it is in some sense misguided.  But I do have my (perhaps bad) reasons.  I'm not trying make an "installer" at all.  This is not meant to be distributed to the world at large.  This is (or will be) an internal tool.  I want to be able to tell someone: "here's a 40-line (or 80-line, or whatever) Perl script that will solve your problem".  Not: "here, install a few hundred megs of STUFF and it will solve your problem".

Comment: Sorry, but you're being unclear about this alternative question you suggest I post.  But if you leave me here, then so be it.  I've certainly used more than enough of your time.  And I sincerely thank you.  Rather than just accept my question at face value, you've attempted to see through to the underlying problem and solve that.  It made me a bit grumpy because it felt like you were trying to answer a question I didn't ask and ignoring the one I did ask, but the impulse is a good one.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060323-00/?p=31803

Comment: See also [*The XY Problem*](http://xyproblem.info/). It happens all the time. I can't and shouldn't formulate a better question for you as I know almost nothing about your problem. I think my job is done in that you have understood my point. No apology was necessary. I will guarantee that, if you bear my ideas in mind, you will get much more useful answers when you ask about how to resolve your predicament.